# MatSort exclude few rows not column

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material

[image] As per the screenshot, exclude empty Rows From "Date" when user clicks on Date for sorting.  The empty rows exists because of ngIf applied on that row. Requirement is rows with empty column values should come at top or bottom of the table when user sorts on Date. Similarly the same rows should sort when there is data in other columns.

Current code:
app.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" style="width:90%" matSortActive='date' matSortDirection='desc' matSort>
```

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
    <th>
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date </mat-header-cell></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > 
      <ng-container *ngIf="element.status =='Active'" >        
        {{element.date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}} </ng-container>      
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

app.component.ts

```
 @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;    
  }
```

Not sure sortingDataAccessor a best fit as I used the header column for filter. This filter allows user to perform multiple selection in each column.

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name
      <mat-select   name="{{filterSelectObj[1].columnProp}}" [(ngModel)]="filterSelectObj[1].modelValue"
      (selectionChange)="filterChange(filterSelectObj[1],$event)">
      <mat-option value="">-- Select {{filterSelectObj[1].name}} --</mat-option>
      <mat-option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of filterSelectObj[1].options">{{item}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select> 
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
      <ng-container >
        <a href="javascript: void(0);" style="color: blue;" (click)="navigate(element.name)">
          {{element.name}} </a> 
      </ng-container> </td>
  </ng-container>
```

The sort to be on pageload and need to know what should be the condition. Because this condition is not working.

```
case 'date': return ((a[sort.active] ? new Date(a[sort.active]).getTime() : 1) < (b[sort.active] ? new Date(b[sort.active]).getTime() : 1) ? 1 : -1) * (isAsc ? -1 : 1); <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Mat sort doesn't work like you think it does. You made a `matColumnDef="date"`, so matSort will sort your rows based on `row.date`. Not less, not more.
MatSort doesn't know you have an ngIf in your td. So it will compare your row using its date even if your row status is not "Active".

So what you have to do is override the sorting function `sortingDataAccessor`, using your own sort, which, when sorting on date column, will consider the status to define your row order.